# What is a good distribution to model average sales

Tags: distributions, forecasting, count-data

I would like to run a monte carlo simulation for a financial model what needs to predict sales.  I have somewhat successfully done this if I assume the average order size is normally distributed (at say 80) and has a standard deviation (of say 30).  However, the problem is that the minimum sale of course can't be less than 0.  Can someone suggest a good alternative distribution (or technique for working with a normal distribution) to handle this problem (I am sure it must be a common enough scenario!).  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sales are often assumed to be [Poisson distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), based on the Poisson's properties of modeling "the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time and/or space if these events occur with a known average rate and independently of the time since the last event", to quote from Wikipedia - which one could argue applies to people buying stuff.

A little more thinking leads us to think about pantry loading, stocking up or hoarding, which would lead to overdispersed data, which can be modeled using the [negative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

However, sales are often also seasonal or driven by promotions and/or price changes, so you should really think about including such factors in your model, which is when you will end up with the regression variants of the above, i.e., [Poisson regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) or negative binomial regression.

And you are right in that this is a common scenario. People make their living doing this. Like yours truly ;-)

Comment: Thanks Stephan....I see from your profile you are definitely the man to answer this question!  I will experiment with all of the above.