# How Negative Binomial Distribution and negative bionomial regression can be used to sales forecast?

Tags: regression, distributions, forecasting, binomial-distribution

My first question here. Due to the improper inventory management we seem to have dispersed sales, and the stores are unable to meet the demand because items are being out of stock. There are so much variation in sales due to the items being out of stock.

We normally tried to forecast the sales using Arima Time Series, which is pretty good, but it can't be nice enough for the products which have very dispersed data. I landed to this [answere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49919/what-is-a-good-distribution-to-model-average-sales?newreg=d82681212a3b4bc29be2422472bd0ff9) which of course is of help. I also found a paper about it although haven't read it yet [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1520-6750(199609)43:6%3C839::AID-NAV4%3E3.0.CO;2-5/abstract). It too seems to suggest the Negative binomial distribution. And as much as I know for forecasting the sales, I could use Negative binomial regression. But can anyone please help me understand how this can be actually used. I do understand what is Negative bionomial distribution is, but nothing more than that. And I want to know about it more. If anybody has used it for such forecast of dispersed data, any thought would be of great help.